# SQL Insert when not exist Update if exist with mutliple rows in Target-Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, where table A has to be Updated or insert a row base on existing. I tried this by using JOINS EXCEPT and MERGE statement but I have one problem i can't solve. so here is an example :

Table A (Attribut-Table)

```
attr   | attrValue | prodID
--------------------------
  4    |   2       |   1
-------------------------- 
  3    |   10      |   2
--------------------------
  1    |   7       |   2
--------------------------
  3    |   10      |   3
--------------------------
  6    |   9       |   3
--------------------------
  1    |   4       |   3
--------------------------
```

Table P(Product-Table)

```
prodID | stock   |
------------------
  1    |  1
------------------
  2    |  0
------------------
  3    |  1
------------------
  4    |  1
------------------
```

Now what i would like to do the following in SQL:

All products, that has Stock > 0 should have an entry in Table A with attr = 6 and attrValue = 9

All products, that has Stock < 1 should have an entry in Table A with attr = 6 and attrValue = 8

i need a SQL Query to do that because my problem is that there are multiple entries for a prodID in Table A

That is what i am thinking of:

Fist check if any entry for the prodID(in Table B) exist in Table A, if not INSERT INTO Table A ( attr=6 and, attrValue = 8/9 (depends on Stock), prodID

If there is already an entry for the prodID in Table A with the attr = 6, then Update this row and set attrValue to 8/9 (depending on stock)

***so I am looking for a translation of "my thoughts" to a sqlQuery***

thanks for helping.

(using: SQL SERVER Express 2012 and HEIDI SQL for management)

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: SQL SERVER Express 2012 and HEIDI SQL for management

Comment: Why haven't you actually done what you are thinking of?  It should work fine.   It's not clear what you tried and what was the "one problem you can't solve".

Comment: my problem is the query, i cant "translate" my thoughts to get the query.. what i tried was always added the attributes and even to the wrong ones. i just looking for some help how is the best way to do this? (there seems sometning i am not aware or thinking of, and i don't know what it is) so if there is any hint would be great

Comment: The INSERT half is the set of P rows   `WHERE NOT EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.prodId = P.ProId and attr = 6`   and the UPDATE half is the set of P rows   `WHERE EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.prodId = P.ProId and attr = 6 [and optionally extra test here for excluding rows that require no change]`   .

Comment: thanks, that (NOT EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM...)  is actually something i didnt think of, and looks quite easy...

Answer (score 2):

Since your "attr 6" row is 100 % derivable from the state of the P table, it is a poor idea to store that row redundantly in A.

This is better :

(1) Define a first view ATTR6_FOR_P as SELECT prodID, 6 as attr, CASE (...) as attrValue from P.  The CASE expression chooses the value 8 or 9 according to stock value in P.

(2) Define a second view A_EXT as A UNION ATTR6_FOR_P.  (***)

Now changes in stock will always immediately be reflected in A_EXT without having to update explicitly.

(***) but beware of column ordering because SQL UNION does not match columns by name but by ordinal position instead.

Comment: but actually, these two tables are given, i cannot change this. the attributes of a Product are all stored in this Table A, now i have to iterate through all products and insert or update the specific attribut.